# Retrieve and format results from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

tbl_marks:

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+
|examid | section1  | section2  | section3  | section4  |    year  |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+ 
|E1     |       100 |      101  |      102  |      103  |    2016  |  
|E2     |       200 |      201  |      202  |      203  |    2015  |
|E3     |       300 |      301  |      302  |      303  |    2014  | 
|E4     |           |           |           |           |    2013  |
|E5     |      400  |      401  |      402  |      403  |    2016  |
|E6     |      500  |      501  |      502  |      503  |    2015  |
|E7     |      600  |      601  |      602  |      603  |    2014  |
|E8     |           |      701  |           |      703  |    2013  |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

tbl_student:

```
+-------+-----+---------+
|name   | sid | rollnum |
+-------+-----+---------+
|cheery |   1 |      X1 |
|apple  |   2 |      X2 |
+-------+-----+---------+
```

tbl_exam:

```
+--------+------+
|examnum |  sid |
+--------+------+
|     E1 |    1 |
|     E2 |    1 |
|     E3 |    1 |
|     E4 |    1 |
|     E5 |    2 |
|     E6 |    2 |
|     E7 |    2 |
|     E8 |    2 |
+--------+------+
```

Expected Output:

Section1, 2, 3, 4 represent scores of section1, 2, 3, 4 of an exam. 
Please note that if score of a section is null, it should be replaced by zeros (000).

Final output table has column - scores which is concatenated result of scores of all sections of a particular year. score1 represent concatenated result of all sections scores of year 2016. Similarly score2 - 2015, score3 - 2014 and etc.

Output should have 2 Rows for two persons with 5 columns - roll num, concatenated section scores of 2016, 2015, 2014 and 2013.

```
+------+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|  num |  score1    |  score2     |  score3     |   score4    |
+------+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|   X1 |100101102103| 200201202203| 300301302303| 000000000000|
|   X2 |400401402403| 500501502503| 600601602603| 000702000703|
+------+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @Jens Thank you for helping format table. Appreciate it. I tried to follow format rules. I am not able to get where am I doing wrong.

Comment: Encapsulate them in code blocks.

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand what is section1, section2, etc ...

Comment: @Jens It worked. Thanks

Comment: I think one way is to create a new temporary table duplicating tbl_marks table and adding an extra column to it which is sid of tbl_student table. Now we can use GROUP_CONCAT and concat on section scores (section1, section2, etc)  grouped by sid.  Any thoughts if this is a good approach or Can we  acheive the result without creating a new table ?

Comment: @JeanDoux I added more details  to my question regarding section1, score1 and etc. Please let me know if anything not clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st step : 
**Join**

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_student t_s
 LEFT JOIN tbl_exam t_e ON t_e.sid = t_s.sid 
 LEFT JOIN tbl_marks t_m ON t_m.examid = t_e.examnum
```

2nd step : 
**Select with case / when**

```
    SELECT t_s.rollnum as "num",
        CASE 
          WHEN t_m.year = '2016' THEN CONCAT_WS('',t_m.section1, t_m.section2, t_m.section3, t_m.section4)
        END AS score1,
        CASE 
          WHEN t_m.year = '2015' THEN CONCAT_WS('',t_m.section1, t_m.section2, t_m.section3, t_m.section4)
        END AS score2,
        CASE 
          WHEN t_m.year = '2014' THEN CONCAT_WS('',t_m.section1, t_m.section2, t_m.section3, t_m.section4)
        END AS score3,
        CASE 
          WHEN t_m.year = '2013' THEN CONCAT_WS('',t_m.section1, t_m.section2, t_m.section3, t_m.section4)
        END AS score4
   FROM tbl_student t_s
     LEFT JOIN tbl_exam t_e ON t_e.sid = t_s.sid 
     LEFT JOIN tbl_marks t_m ON t_m.examid = t_e.examnum
```

We are getting in the right direction here.

3rd step : 
**MAX & GROUP BY**

We need to group all the result by rollnum, so all the others selected column need to be aggregate functions.

```
    SELECT t_s.rollnum as "num",
        MAX(CASE 
          WHEN t_m.year = '2016' THEN CONCAT_WS('',t_m.section1, t_m.section2, t_m.section3, t_m.section4)
        END AS) score1,
        MAX(CASE 
          WHEN t_m.year = '2015' THEN CONCAT_WS('',t_m.section1, t_m.section2, t_m.section3, t_m.section4)
        END) AS score2,
        MAX(CASE 
          WHEN t_m.year = '2014' THEN CONCAT_WS('',t_m.section1, t_m.section2, t_m.section3, t_m.section4)
        END) AS score3,
        MAX(CASE 
          WHEN t_m.year = '2013' THEN CONCAT_WS('',t_m.section1, t_m.section2, t_m.section3, t_m.section4)
        END) AS score4
   FROM tbl_student t_s
     LEFT JOIN tbl_exam t_e ON t_e.sid = t_s.sid 
     LEFT JOIN tbl_marks t_m ON t_m.examid = t_e.examnum
   GROUP BY num
```

Last step : **Coalesce**

```
    SELECT t_s.rollnum as "num",
        MAX(CASE 
          WHEN t_m.year = '2016' THEN CONCAT_WS('',COALESCE(t_m.section1,'000'), COALESCE(t_m.section2,'000'), COALESCE(t_m.section3,'000'), COALESCE(t_m.section4,'000'))
        END AS) score1,
        MAX(CASE 
          WHEN t_m.year = '2015' THEN CONCAT_WS('',COALESCE(t_m.section1,'000'), COALESCE(t_m.section2,'000'), COALESCE(t_m.section3,'000'), COALESCE(t_m.section4,'000'))
        END) AS score2,
        MAX(CASE 
          WHEN t_m.year = '2014' THEN CONCAT_WS('',COALESCE(t_m.section1,'000'), COALESCE(t_m.section2,'000'), COALESCE(t_m.section3,'000'), COALESCE(t_m.section4,'000'))
        END) AS score3,
        MAX(CASE 
          WHEN t_m.year = '2013' THEN CONCAT_WS('',COALESCE(t_m.section1,'000'), COALESCE(t_m.section2,'000'), COALESCE(t_m.section3,'000'), COALESCE(t_m.section4,'000'))
        END) AS score4
   FROM tbl_student t_s
     LEFT JOIN tbl_exam t_e ON t_e.sid = t_s.sid 
     LEFT JOIN tbl_marks t_m ON t_m.examid = t_e.examnum
   GROUP BY num
```

With this you should get the result expected, I can't test it so I may have done some mistakes, leave a comment if it doesn't work.